# Change text color in gauge R

Tags: css, r, flexdashboard

I have the follow `rmarkdown` file:

````
---
title: Gauge
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    theme: yeti
---

### Probability
```{r}
library(flexdashboard)

gauge(
   value = 56, min = 1, max = 100, symbol = "%", 
   gaugeSectors(colors = c("#008cba")), label = "Index"
)
 ```
````

How edit:

`56%`, `1`, `100` and `Index`

with CSS?

I tried change the follow element into `<style> ... </style>`:

```
.chart-wrapper {
  background-color: #222c3d; /*change background-color. Work*/
  color: yellow !important; /*change text color. Doesn't work*/
}
```

to change the color to yellow. But without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
text {
  fill: yellow !important;
}
``
```